# Passing Data from View to Controller using ViewModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I want to pass Data of a Form from view to Controller with ViewModel is that possible?? I am getting null while sending data. My Code is :

My ViewModel contain model class reference. The data which i want to pass is for two model i.e MasterSchoolInfo  and MasterUserInfo, but on submitting the posted value in controller is showing bull. Any help on this will be very helpful. I am new to Asp.Net MVC.

If i am passing Models to the contoller, then that is working fine, but once i changed it to viewmodel it started posting null to controller.

I idea behind changing from Model to ViewModel was because i want to pass data for two different Models and use them in the controller.

**ViewModel**

```
namespace ABC.ViewModels
{
    public class UserInfoViewModel
    {
        public MasterSchoolInfo School { get; set; }
        public MasterTeacherInfo Teacher{ get; set; }
        public MasterStudentInfo Student { get; set; }
        public MasterParentInfo Parent { get; set; }
        public MasterUserInfo User { get; set; }
        public MasterUserRole Role { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult CreateSchool(UserInfoViewModel _usrData)
{
    var content = string.Empty;
    if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserEmail"))) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserRole"))))
    {
        int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId"));
        string UserEmail = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserEmail"));
        string UserRole = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserRole"));
        byte[] salt = encryption.generatePasswordSalt("school");
        string password = encryption.generateHashedPassword("school", salt);
        if (UserRole == "Super Administrator")
        {
            _usrData.School.CreatedBy = UserEmail;
            _usrData.School.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            _usrData.School.ApprovalStatus = true;
            _usrData.School.Status = true;
            MasterUserInfo userInfo = new MasterUserInfo();
            userInfo.RoleId = 4;
            userInfo.EmailId = _usrData.School.PrimaryEmailId;
            userInfo.Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt).ToString();
            userInfo.Password = password;
            userInfo.CreatedBy = UserEmail;
            userInfo.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            userInfo.ApprovalStatus = true;
            userInfo.Status = true;
            //string[] str = schoolInfo.PrimaryEmailId.Split('.');
            //userInfo.Username = str[0].ToString();
            userInfo.Username = _usrData.User.Username.ToString();
            MasterSchoolInfo masterSchool = _context.Set<MasterSchoolInfo>().LastOrDefault();
            if (masterSchool != null)
            {
                var lastschoolcode = masterSchool.OpinschoolCode;                   
                var val = lastschoolcode.Substring(4, lastschoolcode.Length - 4);
                int r = Convert.ToInt32(val) + 1;
                string newusercode = "IESC000" + r;
                userInfo.UserCode = newusercode;
                _usrData.School.OpinschoolCode = newusercode;
            }
            else
            {
                string newusercode = "IESC000" + 1;
                userInfo.UserCode = newusercode;
                _usrData.School.OpinschoolCode = newusercode;
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                _context.MasterUserInfo.Add(userInfo);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                MasterUserInfo masterUser = _context.Set<MasterUserInfo>().Last();
                _usrData.School.UserId = masterUser.Id;
                _context.MasterSchoolInfo.Add(_usrData.School);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                TempData["Message"] = "School Added Successfully!";
                content = "Success";
            }
            else
            {
                content = "Error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            content = "Error";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        content = "Error";
    }
    return Content(content);
}
```

Comment: _"If i am passing Models to the contoller, then that is working fine, but once i changed it to viewmodel it started posting null to controller"_ what you mean under `Model` and `ViewModel` o_O?.

Comment: Model means the data was passed directly using the model class for MasterSchoolInfo and that was working fine, but now when i changed it to pass via ViewModel, it posting null @SeM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example if your Code is :

```
 public class MasterSchoolInfo 
 {
          public string name{get;set;}
 }
```

you should implement input in view:

```
<input type="text" name="school.name">
```

Comment: Thanks @soroosh. This was the thing which i missed. I was using asp-for so  i thought that would be sufficient. Thanks a lot Buddy

Comment: Normally you can use asp-for: <input asp-for="Model.School.Name" />.